# Converting Command skill from Rogue Trader to Fate Core

Tags: fate, skills, conversion, rogue-trader, fate-core

My group worked hard to get through the first two ranks in our Rogue Trader campaign, but we keep finding new flaws in the d100 system used by FFG. Finally we've decided to try out more likeable (and hype!) Fate Core system.

I transfered most of the stuff during one-hour session, original FATE was designed to be a "conversion tool" after all, but there is one question though. There is no direct counterpart for Command skill in the Fate and I have these options:

- Make a new skill. *It disperses player's choice but makes a strong presence in the game: Would I have a Command:4 (top skill), I'd be a renown officer but less other things.*
- Let commanding characters take an aspect to reflect this fact. *Will keep core engine concise, but aspect activation costs an FP and is situational. It will be required to "command" with some other skill, say Charm, to activate the aspect.*
- Make it a stunt. *Again, no additional skill, rolling Charm, but gives you a free and persistent bonus to command attempts, no cost. Stunts are precious as there are only three slots for them at the beginning.*
- Make it a stunt & a privilege. *Same, but stunt doesn't give you bonus to command actions -- it permits you to perform them. Without a stunt you are not able to issue commands at all.*

What would you recommend to do?

Mind you, you must not be a Fate expert to answer. I'm looking for people who has Rogue Trader experience and will help me to keep the ambiance of military action/swashbuckling/trade prince play intact.

Command is used extensively by rogue trader class (from eight classes total), less so by others -- void-master and missionary, seneschal and astropath transcendent. Obviously it allows you to issue a command to your subordinates -- level of success defines how zealous they gonna be and how many of them will listen to you.

Rogue trader usually governs a massive ship population (20k+), other classes hold officer stations here and there. Also Command is used as an "attack" skill during boarding action in space combat and has a lot of "overcome problem" use in general ship management, again that's for rogue trader mostly.

Comment: Probably a stunt—but the great thing about Fate is that it's flexible, so any of these will probably *work* fine. You just have to decide which feels more right to you.

Comment: If you add a little detail about the purpose of Command and the ambience of RT, then FATE people could weigh in more confidently--as I'm eager to.

Comment: You should think about how much have you used the Command skill, and how much importance had it in the sessions you already played. Given an idea of the importance of the skill, would make it easier to chose an option. Just try to figure out how the past Command actions would have been resolved with each option, and how balanced the characters are with any. Sorry I can't help more, but I have never played FATE nor RT, although I have read both, and I would love to play RT some day (with any system).

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Correct, and this ambiguity confuses me. Right now I'm leaning toward the stunt option, but other arguments are more than welcome.

Comment: @BESW Done. Right now all that feels to be a personal choice, but also I'm aware that it will make a big difference in a long play.

Comment: Ah, with the edit that sounds like a skill, and a core one for that character concept ("class").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would go for the **skill** option from what you described. As it seems, it is one of the core skills in RT and there's no reason why it shouldn't be so in your Fate Core game.

Only that you have to clarify the four actions for the new skill

**Overcome:** Used mostly for removing negative aspects on crewmembers, also for accomplishing big things with the help of a big crew.

**Create Advantage:** Rally your crew, get them briefed and ready for the challenges ahead.

**Attack:** Command and coordinate any military maneuver executed by the crew. Also used to overrule other officers if there is a conflict of objectives.

**Defend:** As attack above, but on the receiving end of the same.

Comment: Thanks! Action descriptions really drove the point home.

Comment: I'm not so sure about your attack and defend descriptions. At the most generic level, Attack is about inflicting stress (as the book says, "you try to harm someone in a conflict").  Likewise, Defend is used to prevent harm. While I can see Command used to undermine someone's status ("social" or "mental" conflict), commanding and coordinating are probably Overcome / Create advantage actions. Note that there is nothing wrong with a Skill that has no Attack component in its basic form. I can see a Stunt to allow Command to Attack an enemy troops' morale, though, if such rules are used.

Comment: I usually try to keep things flexible as long as a sensible explanation can be made. Maybe command is no good for tactics or strategy, but helps with the execution of such plans.